# Changing product thumbnail sizes in WooCommerce 3.3

Tags: wordpress, image, woocommerce, settings, product

I'm having some issues changing product thumbnail/image sizes in WooCommerce 3.3.

I used to be able to do this in Admin under WooCommerce > Settings > Products > Display. But I don't see the display tab anymore.

Has this functionality been moved or is there any other way to change image sizes now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In WooCommerce version 3.3 this settings are now located in the customizer and have been deeply enhanced.

[image]

See this related documentation: [WC 3.3 Image size improvements](https://woocommerce.wordpress.com/2017/12/11/wc-3-3-image-size-improvements/)

Comment: Thanks, That helped me out. At first I couldn't find it in the customizer. Simply opening the WooCommerce tab isn't enough. You also need to open  a product page.